# Sympy simplify inequalities with square multiples

Tags: python, sympy

I have an inequality that is riddled with factors that are a priori positive for real-valued variables.  It would be nice if I could get sympy to just 'deal with them'.

For example:

```
import sympy
x,y = sympy.symbols('x y')
sympy.simplify((x**2 + 1)*y > 0)
# (x**2+1)*y > 0 (sympy does nothing)
```

Now, it seems pretty clear that `(x**2+1)*y > 0` iff `y>0` since `(x**2+1)` is always positive for real `x`.  In other words, some reasonable function of simplifying such things might give:

```
simplify_positive_terms((x**2+1)*y > 0)
# y > 0
```

Is there a sympy function that will allow it to simplify these sort of things?

**Note** that the above is only a simple example, and I do not, in general, just want to solve for `y`.

Comment: As a comment: `x**2` is not always positive. It is non-negative.

Comment: @Bartlomiej good point.  The example holds for `x**2 + 1` instead of `x**2`, so I have edited the question to reflect that.  Cheers.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your intention? What do you mean by "deal with them"? What is the expected output for the input you've provided?

Comment: @YakovDan, rearranged to highlight the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
import sympy

def simplify_inequality(e):
    ''' 
    Assume e is an instance of either one of the following:
    sympy.core.relational.StrictGreaterThan
    sympy.core.relational.GreaterThan
    sympy.core.relational.StrictLessThan
    sympy.core.relational.LessThan

    Also, assume that the e is an inequality of the form Mul(f,g..,z) > 0

    '''
    lefthand_side = e.args[0]
    righthand_side= e.args[1]
    if not isinstance(lefthand_side,sympy.mul.Mul):
        return e

    multiplicands = lefthand_side.args
    needed_factors = []
    for factor in multiplicands:
        if len(factor.free_symbols) != 1: # if it has more than one variable, don't try to simplify
            needed_factors.append(factor)

        else:
            result_set = sympy.solveset(factor,factor.free_symbols.pop(),sympy.S.Reals) # see if there are any solutions over the reals   
            if not result_set.is_EmptySet: # there are solutions, this factor is can't be simplified
                needed_factors.append(factor)
            else:    
                free_sym = factor.free_symbols.pop()
                if factor.subs(free_sym,0) > 0: # ok, this factor is always positive, it can go away
                    pass
                else: # we still need it
                    needed_factors.append(factor)

    new_lefthand_side = sympy.mul.Mul(*needed_factors)
    return e.func(*(new_lefthand_side,righthand_side))
```

This should work on inequalities of the type you provided. This function won't simplify factors that are a priori negative, or that are multivariate. But I think it's a reasonable starting point